# Intro repeats a few frames when using onClipEvent(enterFrame) and loadVars onLoad

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I am using the following code to load my flash file, contact a php script and decide what frame to play based on the results. THat is all working fine, the problem is that when the animation starts from Frame 2 - gotoAndPlay(2) - it seems to repeat a few frames over and over until the whole animation is complete.

I have done some reading up and the enterFrame is called many times so I can understand why the problem is there but I don't know how to resolve it.

The interesting thing is, when I just use gotoAndPlay(2) in the if loaded section, it all works fine. It's only when it's in the onLoad for the loadVars that causes it to break.

Using: Flash CS5 and Actionscript 2.0

Can someone help please?

```
onClipEvent (load) {
    total = _root.getBytesTotal();
}

onClipEvent (enterFrame) {  
    loaded = _root.getBytesLoaded();
    percent = int(loaded/total*100);
    text = percent+"%";
    gotoAndStop(percent);
    if (loaded == total) { //could also be percent == 100
        var lvContent = new LoadVars();
        lvContent.onLoad = function(success: Boolean) {
            if (success) {
                trace("Page: " + this.pageID);       
                if (this.pageID == "29") { //If it's the home page then play the full animation. If not .. don't.
                    _root.gotoAndPlay(5);
                }else{
                    _root.gotoAndPlay(90);
                }
            }else{
                _root.gotoAndStop(90); //If all else fails, don't do the intro.
            }
        }   
        lvContent.load("http://URL/Flash/getID.php");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't manege to get this sorted so in the end I just stopped the animation from starting.